Does Jesus mean "Salvation" or "God is Salvation"?
I'm unsure as to whether Jesus means "Salvation", or "God is Salvation".
Strongs tells me that "Jesus" (G2424) is derived from the Hebrew, H3091.
H3091 is yᵊhôšûaʿ, translated into English as 'Joshua' and meaning "God (Yahweh) is Salvation".
However, I've often heard the Hebrew name for Jesus pronounced as "Yeh-SHOO-ah" (not Yeh-hosh-oo-AH, as the Hebrew for Joshua is pronounced).
Whereas, one of the words for salvation, is H3444, yᵊšûʿâ, which is pronounced "Yay-SHOO-ah".
So you see that one of the Hebrew words for salvation sounds nearly exactly like I've heard Yeshua pronounced. And yet, according to the Strongs, Jesus is meant to be derived from the Hebrew word for Joshua ("God is Salvation").
Matthew 1:21 doesn't seem to prove either way, only making reference to salvation, not the name of God:

She will bear a Son; and you shall call His name Jesus, for He will save His people from their sins.

I know there is some helpful dialogue on this question, here , but my question is a little different in that I'm asking about H3444, and why it is not the origin of "Jesus" alone, whereas H3091, is.

This is a linguistically tortuous story.

Our English Jesus comes a transliteration of the Greek Ἰησοῦς (Iesous).
In turn, the Greek Ἰησοῦς (Iesous) is a transliteration of the late Hebrew יֵשׁוּעַ (Yoshua).
The late Hebrew יֵשׁוּעַ (Yoshua) is a contraction of the early Hebrew name יְהוֺשׁוּעַ (Yehoshua).
This name יְהוֺשׁוּעַ is a compound of two words: Yeho (a contraction of the divine name and tetragrammaton, יְהוָֹה (YHWH); and a contraction of תְּשׁוּעָה (teshuah) = "salvation".

Together, the name Jehoshua (= Jesus) = "The LORD/Jehovah is Salvation"

Thank you @Dottard. This succinct answer works for me. I had heard that contractions might have something to do with it. And transliterations of transliterations makes sense, too.

My answer was taken from https://researchsupportsthetruth.wordpress.com/
“Originally, the name of the Messiah was pronounced Yehoshua. This is the Messiah’s original name and meant ‘Jehovah is salvation’. It is quite evident that the modern form “Jesus” does not even remotely resemble the original name that the disciples used. This is fact. “-Encyclopedia Americana (Vol.16, p. 41)
“the construction of theophoric names, starting with the letters “Jeho” is evidence that God’s name is actually ‘Jehovah’(and that Christ’s name is actually Jehoshua)” – Smith’s 1863 “A Dictionary of the Bible” Section 2.1
The English name “Joshua” is a rendering of the Hebrew language “Yahoshua”, meaning “Yehowah” is salvation”.-^ A Hebrew and English Lexicon of the Old Testament Francis Brown, with S.R. Driver and C.A. Briggs, based on the lexicon of William Gesenius. Oxford: Clarendon Press. p. 221 & 446
“Yehoshua may refer to: Yehoshua, the Hebrew name of Joshua, the son of Nun or of Jesus, the Christ; since both Hebrew names are identical.
Joshua (Hebrew: יְהוֹשֻׁעַ‎‎ Yehoshuaʿ; and both have the same meaning.  Why do some Bibles translate it as ‘Joshua’, while others translate it as ‘Jesus’? There is a definite inconsistency here.”  “Jehoshua, meaning ‘Jehovah is Salvation’.”-The Catholic Encyclopedia Vol. 8, p. 374
“To transliterate the Hebrew name ‘Yeshua’ (or ‘Yehoshua’) into English, we merely go to (another man with the same name as Christ), ‘Yeshua’ (or Yehoshua) (who was the son of Nun) (He is mentioned in The Old Testament as well as The New Testament.  Thus his name is pronounced Yeshua (or Yehoshua) both in Hebrew and in English – a perfect transliteration. What could be simpler?” (The letter ‘J’ replaces the letter ‘Y’ in English). –IS JESUS a PAGAN NAME? YHWH is Elohim – Yahushua is the Messiah
by Yahkov Hartley

Thanks you @Alex Balilo for these references!

"It is quite evident that the modern form “Jesus” does not even remotely resemble the original name that the disciples used. This is fact." - Encyclopedia Americana (Vol.16, p. 41). With exaggeration like that labeled as "fact," I will know to steer clear of this encyclopedia!
